# Zoomable Forced Layout - Make SVG rect fixed position

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a forced layout that is bounded within a rectangle of a specific width and height. I have added a zoom function along with the auto-sizing properties to the chart's svg, so that it can be zoomed in with the mouse roll.

Issues are: The rectangle that I add via 'rect' variable becomes draggable (no idea why) and on zooming, the rectangle itself is zooming in as well... which I am not after.

Summing up:

A. I need the rectangle to be fixed on the spot (should not act like a draggable object)
B. I need the zoom on the layout itself, while keeping the rect width as fixed.

```
var width = 1024;
var height = 768;

var xx = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0,1000]).range([0, width]);
var yy = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0,1000]).range([0, height]);

var svg = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
            .attr("pointer-events", "all")
                .style("fill", '#000000')
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")")
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(xx).y(yy).scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append('g');


 rect = svg.append('rect')
           .attr('width', width+10)
           .attr('height', height+10)
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")")
           .attr('fill', '#000000');


 function redraw() {
          svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
          + "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
       }
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Your binding your rect to your svg which has the zoom attached.  Try separating them.

Comment: tried that as well. Appended the rect to the body alone but still the same behavior. The svg appears to be draggable which is a pain. Any thoughts on how to suppress this behavior?

Comment: two question can you post a fiddle with a working example and what's the purpose of the rectangle?